# jclouds discovery is not working in Hazelcast 3.6 EA

Tags: hazelcast, jclouds

I was trying to use new `jclouds` based discovery mechanism in `Hazelcast` 3.6 EA. However, couldn't make it work using exactly same credentials as for native AWS discovery. Here are two configs:

Native AWS (works):

```xml
<network>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false" />
        <tcp-ip enabled="false" />
        <aws enabled="true">
            <access-key>AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXX</access-key>
            <secret-key>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</secret-key>
            <region>eu-west-1</region>
            <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
        </aws>
    </join>
</network>
```

`jclouds` (doesn't work):

```xml
<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
</properties>

<network>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false" />
        <tcp-ip enabled="false" />
        <aws enabled="false" />
        <discovery-strategies>
            <discovery-strategy class="com.hazelcast.jclouds.JCloudsDiscoveryStrategy" enabled="true">
                <properties>
                    <property name="provider">aws-ec2</property>
                    <property name="identity">AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXX</property>
                    <property name="credential">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</property>
                    <property name="regions">eu-west-1</property>
                </properties>
            </discovery-strategy>
        </discovery-strategies>
    </join>
</network>
```

More about setup: 2 instances which are part of the same Elastic Beanstalk application. Port 5701 is open publicly (for testing). DEBUG log level enabled for Hazelcast. AWS user has permission to perform `ec2:describe*`

With `jclouds` discovery enabled, each node only see itself:

```
DEBUG: Log4jFactory.java:93  [172.31.5.117]:5701 [dev] [3.6-EA] This node will assume master role since no possible member where connected to.
DEBUG: Log4jFactory.java:93  [172.31.5.117]:5701 [dev] [3.6-EA] This node is being set as the master
DEBUG: Log4jFactory.java:93  [172.31.5.117]:5701 [dev] [3.6-EA] PostJoin master: Address[172.31.5.117]:5701, isMaster: true
INFO : Log4jFactory.java:99  [172.31.5.117]:5701 [dev] [3.6-EA] 
Members [1] {
  Member [172.31.5.117]:5701 this
}
```

Comment: Can you please try 3.6-EA2? We are happy to help you if you still experience the problem. http://hazelcast.org/download/

Comment: @Mesut just tried 3.6-EA3, works perfectly with jclouds and IAM roles. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see Hazelcast 3.6-EA release has issues with JClouds Integration and here is the fix for it.
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/6651